# Datadog Agent installation on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, agent, datadog

I am trying to install the Datadog agent on Windows using PowerShell only, not manual however, the `APIKEY` is not being setup. Is there a way to update/set the `APIKEY` after installation?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a powershell question.  This sounds like an applications question.

Comment: And if you think the problem is with powershell and want it to be treated like a powershell question, we need to see the code.

Comment: You changed the question you originally asked after it was answered. This means the original question and answer are lost to the stack overflow community. This is not in the spirit of stack overflow. Please consider reverting to the original question and starting a new thread for the new question.

Answer (score 1):

First you may need to download the MSI file:

```
$image_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ddagent-windows-stable/ddagent-cli-latest.msi"
$destin = "C:\path\to\downloaded\ddagent-cli-latest.msi"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($image_url, $destin)
```

The actual powershell command for installation (with extra optional arguments included as arguments):

```
msiexec /i C:\path\to\downloaded\ddagent-cli-latest.msi /l*v C:\path\to\installation_log.txt /quiet APIKEY="$DD_API_KEY" HOSTNAME="$HOSTNAME" TAGS=`"$TAGS,COMMA,DELIMITED`
```

It's been a while since i've done this (8 months or so?), so it could be outdated, but it used to work :).

Note, if you're running this from a remote provisioning script, you'll probly have to schedule this to be executed not-remotely so that the installation command can be run with heightened permissions, which i believe is required. And you *may* need to make sure the computer is plugged into the power source (i remember hitting some infuriating issue where that was an arbitrary requirement for Windows scheduled tasks to run, and Windows didn't allow me to configure around that).

Comment: Oh, this actually worked, the key was set properly at the installation. I was also wandering if I can update the APIKEY after the installation was complete. Thank you.

Comment: You can do that, i'm sure, either manually or from powershell. If from powershell, you'd have to find where the datadog configuration file is on the server and use a `sed` -like commandlet to replace the API key argument value with the desired value. Then you would have to restart the Datadog agent for the new config to take effect.

Manually, using the Datadog Agent Manager GUI, this is all very easy.